Rebuilding md raid5
I have linux ubuntu  11 (bullseye) with raid5, 3 disks of 2TB, and I want to add one disk of 2TB.
I did the manual and after umount command I lost my array.
When doing lsblk I see I don't have array mounted, that's logic to me.
lsblk output:
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2               8:2    0   488M  0 part /boot
└─sda3               8:3    0 237.5G  0 part
  ├─SRV--vg-root   254:0    0 236.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─SRV--vg-swap_1 254:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                  8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdb1               8:17   0   1.8T  0 part
sdc                  8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdc1               8:33   0   1.8T  0 part
sdd                  8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
sde                  8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sde1               8:65   0   1.8T  0 part

But when I try to assemble the array using this manual I do the command:
 sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sde

and recieve the following output:
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdb has no superblock - assembly aborted

fdisk -l output is:
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZBX-00A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 16BEE218-DD7C-11EE-8CF6-D8CB8A1409C0

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZBX-22A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 16B93AE7-DD7C-11EE-8CF6-D8CB8A1409C0

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdd: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZBX-00A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BF7FEEC8-7DCE-0A4D-85EA-0AA18AB0EBD7


Disk /dev/sde: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZBX-22A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 16C52C55-DD7C-11EE-8CF6-D8CB8A1409C0

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: PLEXTOR PX-256M6
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 37957460-EE75-440F-AC0D-F3333B740269

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 500117503 498067456 237.5G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/SRV--vg-root: 236.53 GiB, 253973495808 bytes, 496041984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/SRV--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

As I understand I ruined my array. Is it right?
How can I reassemble my array without data lose?
Yes, I have backup to the important things, so if I must I can build a new array.

Try using the partitions when assembling, not the entire drive. Maybe also check with blkid.

@DanielB if I do sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sde1 the output is that the device are busy. but I don't use them. I did restart.

I solved it with the comment of DanielB, but I lost my data...
When I did
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sde1

the output was that the devices are busy, so I googled and found I need to stop the md array. from there the assemble and rebuilding the array was easy.
I don't know what ruined my data, but at least I have a backup for the important things so I can recover the data.
